# usb microphone not workinga

Tags: 20.04, microphone

I bought a usb microphone and tried to make some recordings with audio-recorder but the created recordings were silent
I brought up alsamixer and pressed F4 for input only and it showed from left to right mic boost, capture, capture 1, digital, input source, input source
Both input sources are set to mic
I'm clueless and I wonder why ubuntu is so difficult in audio input handling